# zClip flash video doesn't extend over image in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zclip

I am using zClip to copy text when I click on an image. The flash video that the user is supposed to click on is too small. It doesn't extend over the whole image. I could edit jquery.zclip.js and set a static size, but I don't want to unless I have to.

Area you have to click: http://i.imgur.com/cLfLCRb.png

Image area: http://i.imgur.com/jKdKq6r.png

HTML

```
<a data-copy-src="#code1" data-copy-msg="#msg1" href="#" class="copyMe">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q2BP7YR.png" />
</a>
<div id="code1" class="copySrc">copy this</div>
<span id="msg1" class="copyMsg"></span>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
$('.copyMe').zclip({
    path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
        var copySrcSelector = $(this).data('copy-src');
        return $(copySrcSelector).text();
    },
    afterCopy: function() {
        var copyMsgSelector = $(this).data('copy-msg');
        $(copyMsgSelector).html("&#x2714;");
    }
});
```

});